# BQ Scripting - DECLARE: Using schema type of existing table

Tags: google-bigquery

With the new BQ scripting feature, is it possible to declare a variable with the type of an existing table?  Our tables have big schemas and being explicit wouldnt work

Nothing in the documentation shows this, so might not be possible yet.

Assume persons is an existing table....

```
DECLARE aPerson (persons.schema)
```

Type of pseudo code where i want a single variable to be of that schema, or even an array of

```
DECLARE somePersons ARRAY<(persons.schema)>
```

A variable that inherits the schema of an existing table / or in the array example a group of them.

UPDATED ELLIOTT with more meat on the example

Basically there are up to 3 system specific 'profiles' for a given party

Idea is to produce a single version of this, where each system profile is merged based on some rules (internals of each called stored proc)

I get errors related to not declaring variables the types I want to be of the table type (master_party_profile_changed_parties).

Code below hope its not too confusing!

```
DECLARE changedPartyIds ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE numChangedParties, i INT64 DEFAULT 0;

-- below is a workaround (Elliott B from GCP) as you cant declare a variable of a type using an existing tables schema, this is a suggested workaround where the schema needs to come from 'master_party_profile_changed_parties' table
-- create a small temp array and can use this later in select projection.

CREATE TEMP TABLE PartyProfileRawRefdataRow AS
  SELECT t
  FROM `datset.master_party_profile_changed_parties_small` AS t
  LIMIT 1;

-- fetch the changed party ids - they will be changed if any of their profiles have changes since last run date
-- we need to process all changed parties profiles (1 Party -> (*) PartyProfiles) to generate the single 'master' view

SET changedPartyIds = (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(partyId order by partyId)
  FROM
    `sdv-analytics-wt-uat.sdv_bi_derived_events.master_party_profile_changed_parties_small`
);

-- lets process each party in turn now, looking at their profiles, with a specific order of precedence for each master field.
-- while there are parties with changed profiles still to process

WHILE i <= ARRAY_LENGTH(changedPartyIds) DO
  -- for each party, set system1Profile - might be null.  
  -- ERROR ELLIOTT: need to declare careProfile as a type of my source table?
  SET system1Profile = (
    SELECT 
      (SELECT t FROM PartyProfileRawRefdataRow AS t).*
    FROM
      inputProfiles ip
    WHERE
      partyId = changedPartyIds[OFFSET(i)]
  );
  -- for this party, now set system2Profile - might be null. 
  -- ERROR ELLIOTT: need to declare system1Profile as a type?

  SET system2Profile = (
    SELECT 
      (SELECT t FROM PartyProfileRawRefdataRow AS t).*
    FROM
      inputProfiles ip
    WHERE
      partyId = changedPartyIds[OFFSET(i)]
  );

  -- for this party, set a system3 profile - might be null.  
  -- ERROR ELLIOTT: need to declare system3 as a type?

  SET system3Profile = (
    SELECT 
      (SELECT t FROM PartyProfileRawRefdataRow AS t).*
    FROM
      inputProfiles ip
    WHERE
      partyId = changedPartyIds[OFFSET(i)]
  );

  -- ERROR ELLIOTT: need to declare masterProfile fort SP (INOUT) as a type too?  The StoredProc will merge addresses from first 3 according to rules and populate masterProfile sub attribute...tahts just detail, main issue is cannot declare the variables in the first place?

  CALL MasterProfile_mergeAddresses(system1Profile, system2Profile, system3Profile, masterProfile);

  -- Finally, insert the newly derived masterProfile into an actual table.
  INSERT INTO `sdv-analytics-wt-uat.sdv_bi_derived_events.master_party_profile_generation_output_master_profile` VALUES (
    masterProfile
  );

  -- increment counter and move onto next party
  SET i = i + 1; 
END WHILE;
```

Comment: this looks to me as extreme over-engineering and rather can be done in set-based fashion. in any case - as it is today - there is no way to declare variable of unknown type table / struct as you are trying to do - even after Elliott clearly stated this in his answer

Comment: Gee - no need to be so negative to me.  Maybe it is over-engineered (I left out alot of logic intentionally), maybe I didn't quite follow full usage options of this new feature from Elliotts recommendation - we aren't all as good as you....I was just trying to show more real-life example while getting a handle on this is all.....thanks

Comment: sorry if it looked that way - it was not intended to be negative about YOU at all. just provided feedback on what I see. how you would otherwise know that most likely you are in wrong direction (in my opinion of course which is based on decades of real-life examples). obviously I can be wrong - but in any case please don't get this personally - just trying to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for declaring variables with the row types of tables. You could [submit a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0), however, and please link it here if you do. In the meantime, you can create a temporary table with a single row, and then treat it like a variable later. As a sketch:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE PersonRow AS
SELECT t
FROM dataset.persons AS t
LIMIT 1;

SELECT x, y, z, (SELECT t FROM PersonRow AS t).*
FROM dataset.other_table;
```

Comment: Have just submitted that thanks Elliott and noted on the interim workaround.  We use Terraform to provision views currently, is there (will there) be the ability to manage script and stored procedure code from Terraform as well?  Just on 'saving' scripts, do they just get saved as a 'query' like other saved queries (only save query of save view options in the UI)?  Would be great if you could just save these resources to specific datasets like views and have the hierarchical seperation / permissions etc.  At the moment the whole query saved to a flat structure isnt ideal.  Awsome thanks heaps!

Comment: hmmm - just trying this, the ```SELECT x, y, z``` part means I need list out exact variable numbers (your example indicates width of 3)?  Table we are using for this test is 3000 columns wide...

Comment: actually you arent saying that, x, y, z come from some other table.....Ill keep playing with this

Comment: Yes, the x, y, z in this example would come from a different table. You can "save" a script by creating a stored procedure. For Terraform, someone submitted this request: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/4619

Comment: Tried to add some extra context / meat to the exmaple.  I need 4 variables of this complex table type 'master_party_profile_changed_parties_small', validation fails saying I need to declare system1Profile, system2Profile, system3Profile and masterProfile of this complex type......any help appreciated!  Cheers :)